# Using List Indicies is not object oriented? c#

Tags: c#, oop, for-loop, foreach, indexing

In the homework I am doing:

It is stated: "You may NOT use a number to access a tile - if you are using a number to find a tile, then it is most likely your design is not object oriented."

So essentially, my question is this:

If one were to not use an index to get an object from a list of objects, would the only solution be to use a foreach loop, every time you needed to retrieve a specific object?

If not, could you please provide an example (e.x. using a "for loop in an object oriented way", or other solutions instead of using an index)?

My concern is the amount of bloat (in lines) that might be created when not using for loops - and the affect that might have on speed.

e.g., I have the following:

```
for (int i = dimensions-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    map += "-";

    for (int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++)
    {
        //For 4X4Y is 24. 3X4Y is 19. and so on.
        //For 4X3Y is 23. 3X3Y is 18. and so on.
        //As you can see: j * dimensions represents a "generalized" x value. adding it by i, represents its y value.

        Tile currentTile = _game.TileSet[(j * dimensions) + i];

        if (currentTile.Visitor == null)
            map += "X-"; //X implies no robot
        else
            map += "R-"; //R implies robot
    }
}
```

Yes this code is kind of ugly, but my list is formatted in such a way that I can't just use one foreach loop, and split the line on each x amount of tiles per line, as the list is stored vertically, and then horizontally, as opposed to horizontally, and then vertically (which would allow a simple foreach to suffice).

My concern is that if this is "not object oriented" - then using a foreach loop, would require a LOT more iterations.

Anyway, if anyone has an answer to the question I would really appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks.

Edit: Instead of using X and Y values, in a 2D List/Array, the list is 1d, and we are required to use association by having a list of connecting tiles, 4 elements, each element representing a typical compass direction in which the adjacent tile is located. There are no properties - however there is one method which can return an adjacent tile at a specified direction `GetTileAtDirection(Direction)`.

The `tileSet` is a list of 25 elements, with 0 through 4 being the first 5 elements, `X = 0, Y = 0` `X = 0, Y = 1` `X = 0, Y = 2` `X = 0, Y = 3` `X = 0, Y = 4`. For the next five elements, X is incremented by one, representing the next five values in this "Y line"...
Note that there are no X and Y variables in which each tile can be accessed. This is a requirement in the homework.

Comment: Could I also suggest that you not use string concatenation to build an arbitrarily large string (`map`)?

Comment: I think the question means you should be calling a function. I certainly wouldn't guess *additional* code bloat is intended by this guidance.

Comment: If you have to avoid using indexes is there a property on the Tile you could select out using linq using a First?

_game.TitleSet.First(t=> t.Something == somethingelse) ?

Comment: You should probably ask your prof.  Indexing into an array has not a good gotdamn thing to do with OOP.

Comment: If you could describe a bit more what is your homework - this would help to help you.

Comment: don't know enough about the question. Your asking about an example for a concept and not giving enough to build an example with.

Comment: I updated the question, is there enough information now? Note that if a solution can't be found for my specific for loop conundrum, I am still interested in the opinion of others on using indicies "not being object oriented".

Comment: Rather than "object oriented" it's more likely that he was referring to a "functional" style of programming.  A functional style of programming would generally avoid pulling out each individual item from the collection, instead defining actions to be performed on the entire collection.  Accessing items by index isn't inherently not functional, but it's an indication of code that is at least much less likely to have a good functional design.  I assume that's what your teacher meant.

Comment: @Servy, you have to access items by index at some point, otherwise you'd never need to use the `for` loop in OOP. It's just a question of how and when you're accessing the items by index and why. The statement on the homework is very vague to put it mildly.

Comment: @gfish3000 As I said in my comment, the point was likely intended to be made about functional programming, not OO programming.  In functional programming you *don't* really use `for` loops.  It's inherently a very procedural construct, not a functional one.  A functional style of programming would `foreach` over a collection.  At some low level, if it's an array based collection (which would be less common in and of itself in a functional world) it would use arrays, but only the lowest level, the iterator, would be accessing items by index, the rest of the program usually wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one were to not use an index to get an object from a list of
>   objects, would the only solution be to use a foreach loop, every time
>   you needed to retrieve a specific object?

No. I think the idea is that each tile should have a mapping of `Direction` to `Tile`, and `GetTileAtDirection` simply looks it up. The code that creates the tiles would need to assign the relationships, something like this:

```
nextTile = new Tile();
nextTile.AdjacentTiles[Direction.Left] = previousTile;
previousTile.AdjacentTiles[Direction.Right] = nextTile;
```

and so on. Of course, this code would probably be looking up the indices in `TileSet`, but the key is that an individual tile object can be completely independent from it -- the Tile class wouldn't even need a reference to a Game object or TileSet.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense, I supposed I could get the first tile, and populate the list based on each tiles adjacent tile not being null. It would be a bit tricky though, since the first tile is bottom left; however as advised in the OP, formatting one super long string may not be the best way to do that anyway.